# Class Method is not calling

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have the written following class using Class plugin

```
if(typeof tech== 'undefined')tech= {};
window.tech= (function(){
       //tech is a global object I have to add each individual class like 'map' to tech
    }); 
tech.map = Class.extend({
    //Constructor
    init:function(props){
        }
     },
     logError: function(){
     }
});
```

In other JS file I am trying to call init function using tech.map.init(); But the init is not called.What needs to be changed here to call the init()

Comment: Are you using this plugin? http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Comment: yes.when I am using the class like in example provided at above link like var Person.It is working fine.But, now I have to add it to  tech.map object

Comment: Your first two lines are redundant; you're initializing the variable `tech` twice, so get rid of the first line.